# Taking Layout as condition in If statment?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

How should I take any layout as condition in If(Condition of layout)????
What exactly I have to do is to check numbers of child in each linear layout after drop images from one linear layout to another. And also help me out to count number of child in each layout after dropping views.

Comment: try this way "yourLayout".getChildCount()...

Comment: That only gives me the number of child count. Firstly I want to check in which layout the dropping has been made. And how to apply that any particular layout in condition..

Comment: I think you need to explain what you're trying to do more clearly.  Your question currently doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan Firstly I have 12 linear layout in my grid layout. Each linear layout contains image in it. On dragging and dropping images from one layout to another, I am getting id of each image which is dragged and getting id of each layout in which that image is dropped. Now the problem is: In all this layout I have to count the number of child after the dragging stops. And for that Should I have to take layout as condition in any of states???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get child count of a parent layout like this:

```
LinearLayout titleParent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_parent);
int childCount = titleParent.getChildCount();
```

---

you can loop through to check its children and to put a condition 
Eg.,

```
for (int i = 0; i < titleParent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            LinearLayout childLayout = (LinearLayout) titleParent.getChildAt(i); 
            if(childLayout.getId == R.id.child) 
                             // do something 
        }
```

Comment: Will u just look at the above explanation about my working problem